# How to move(without scaling) objects from center of those objects and preserving dimensions

Tags: modeling, dimensions

I had a problem this morning and I don't know how to make it.

I have multiple cylinders that are placed in circle every 20 degrees. I would like to move all of them at once far/near the center and not scaling the cylinders. I would like the preserve the dimensions of the cylinders.

Is there a way to move those objects away from the center and keep dimensions of those objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

1. Set all three scales options to locked on each of the objects you need to move
2. Select all those meshes you need to move
3. With Pivot set to *Median*, just press <kbd>S</kbd> and start moving objects from the center of selection without any scaling

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this option is what you're looking for (*Manipulate Center Points*):

[image]

Comment: Nothing happening when this option is grayed.

Comment: when you activate it, select all your objects and scale, all your objects will come closer without scaling individually, is it not what you want?

Comment: I mean nothing moves when scaling.

Comment: it must be because your "objects" must actually be several meshes within one unique object, in that case I don't think you can do what you want to do, but what you can do is making each mesh a separate object with P > Separate, then use the Manipulate Center Points option, then when you have the result you want you can join back your objects to make one unique object again with ctrl J

Comment: @EricBrochu if your pivot is set to  'Individual Origins' or suchlike, the object pivot-points will just be scaling about themselves, with no effect. Set your Pivot Point to say, 3D cursor, at the point  which you would like your objects to recede from / approach.

Comment: I have for a long time overlooked Manipulate Center Points. Thank you for mentioning it. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/manipulate_center_points.html